# angular material unable to set second parameter in the map-get custom components

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

IM following this guide of createing a custom component color to my buttons.

ive had the same issue like this guy: 
[Angular 2 + Material: Unable to use map-get with 2nd parameter "text", "card" and others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46648928/angular-2-material-unable-to-use-map-get-with-2nd-parameter-text-card-an)

but his solution not working.

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';


@include mat-core();


$bv-brand : (
  50: #e0f3ed,
  100:#b3e0d1,
  200:#80ccb3,
  300:#4db894,
  400:#26a87d,
  500:#009966,
  600:#00915e,
  700: #008653,
  800: #007c49,
  900: #006b38,
  A100: #9affc6,
  A200: #67ffaa,
  A400: #34ff8d,
  A700: #1aff7f,
  contrast: (
    500: white,
    600: white,
    700: white,
    800: white,
    900: white,
    A700: white,
)
    );


$brand-orange: (
  50: #fef3e4,
  100: #fde0bb,
  200: #fccc8e,
  300: #fab861,
  400: #f9a83f,
  500: #f8991d,
  600: #f7911a,
  700: #f68615,
  800: #f57c11,
  900: #f36b0a,
  A100: #ffffff,
  A200: #fff1e9,
  A400: #ffd1b6,
  A700: #ffc19c,
  contrast: (
          500: white,
          600: white,
          700: white,
          800: white,
          900: white,
          A700: white,
  )
);

// mandatory stuff for theming
$primary-palette: mat-palette($bv-brand);
$accent-palette:  mat-palette($brand-orange);
$app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);

// include the custom theme components into a theme object
$app-theme: mat-light-theme($primary-palette, $accent-palette);



@mixin mix-app-theme($app-theme) {

  $primary: map-get($app-theme, primary);
  $accent: map-get($app-theme, accent);


  $bv-brand : map-get($app-theme,primary-palette);

  .mat-button-toggle {
    background-color: mat-color($bv-brand);
    color: mat-color($bv-brand, default-contrast);
  }

  .mat-button-toggle-checked {
    background-color: mat-color($accent);
    color: mat-color($accent, default-contrast);
  }
}

// include the custom theme object into the angular material theme
@include angular-material-theme($app-theme);
// Include the mixin
@include mix-app-theme($app-theme);
```

And im getting this error below:

> ```
>   Argument `$map` of `map-get($map, $key)` must be a map
> ```

The issue is on the this line:

```
  $bv-brand : map-get($app-theme,primary-palette);
```

because when i use the primary variabel instead of primary-palette everying works just fine its like map-get not accept my new variable. 
i tried added foreground like so:

```
  $primary: map-get($app-theme, primary);
  $accent: map-get($app-theme, accent);

  $foreground: map-get($app-theme, foreground); <--ADDED HERE
  $background: map-get($app-theme, background); <-- ADDED HERE

  $bv-brand : map-get($foreground,primary-palette);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I little bit late, but your problem is that you have to add "$".

example:

```
$bv-brand : map-get($app-theme, $primary-palette);
```

I hope helped.