# How to get the current angular theme's color of a specific component (e.g. button hover background)?

Tags: angular, scss-mixins, angular-material-7

I want to have a hover color on a list I display with Angular 7 and material design. Since the `$primary`, `$accent` and `$warn` colors don't serve this purpose very well, I want to get the same color for hovering that a button has when hovering. I am currently using the candy-app-theme and the dark-theme from the [material design multiple-themes example](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming), so I don't define this color myself.

For defining my hovering color I need to query this button hovering color however. Therefore: How do I query this color?

```
@mixin options-component-theme($theme) {
    $primary: map-get($theme, primary);
    $accent: map-get($theme, accent);// Use mat-color to extract individual colors from a palette as necessary.

    //i have tried these two:
    $hover: map-get($theme, hover);
    $focused-button: map-get($theme, focused-button);

    $primary-color: mat-color($primary);
    $accent-color: mat-color($accent);

    .listItemFormat:hover {
    background-color: $focused-button;
```

}

I have tried to get the colors via `hover` and `focused-button`, [as listed in this answer by TimTheEnchanter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45089178/how-to-get-primary-or-accent-color-of-currently-applied-theme-in-angular-materia/45767091#45767091), however this does not work (I end up without any visible hovering effect at all).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My assumption to get the color directly from the theme was wrong, I had to get the palette first. Thus the correct way to do it would be querying (in my case with the focused-button color) the `background` palette first and getting the `focused-button` color from said palette.

The code from the question has to be adjusted thus:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

@mixin options-component-theme($theme) {

    $primary: map-get($theme, primary);
    $accent: map-get($theme, accent);// Use mat-color to extract individual colors from a palette as necessary.

    $background-palette: map-get($theme, background);

    $primary-color: mat-color($primary);
    $accent-color: mat-color($accent);
    $focused-button-color: mat-color($background-palette, focused-button);

   .listItemFormat:hover {
    background-color: $focused-button-color;
   }
}
```

For completeness of the question, here is a copy of the list in the answer I referenced in my original question:

> For completeness, here are the lists of the elements you can get from
>   the different palettes: From the "primary" palette ($primary and
>   $dark-p in my code above):
>
> - default
> - lighter
> - darker
>
> You can also get these same three color values for the $accent and
>   $warn palettes.
>
> From the "foreground" palette ($light-foreground-palette and
>   $dark-foreground-palette in my code above):
>
> - base
> - divider
> - dividers
> - disabled
> - disabled-button
> - disabled-text
> - hint-text
> - secondary-text
> - icon
> - icons
> - text
> - slider-off
> - slider-off-active
>
> From the "background" palette ($light-background-palette and
>   $dark-background-palette in my code above):
>
> - status-bar
> - app-bar
> - background
> - hover
> - card
> - dialog
> - disabled-button
> - raised-button
> - focused-button
> - selected-button
> - selected-disabled-button
> - disabled-button-toggle